# Google Chrome not using Ubuntu's Titlebar and Window Buttons

Tags: google-chrome, themes, 18.04, chromium, titlebar

Here's Chrome:
[image]

And here's Chromium:
[image]

The settings:
[image]

[image]

Any way to fix this in Chrome?

Comment: Is chrome from any snap/flatpack repo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Launch Google Chrome and go to **Settings** from the hamburger menu (three horizontal bars/dots at top right). Then under **Appearance** select *Use GTK+ theme*

Also turn on the **Use system title bar and borders** option.

If it doesn't work right away, reboot your system once.

Comment: Thanks! it worked

Comment: I had missing iconz on compiz, but what interestingly helped me, was actually to disable this setting.